# Attach to Revit process fails with System.ExecutionEngineException

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, revit-api, revit

I'm trying to attach my pluggin/Addin to Revit.
After attaching to process I get the following error

**The application is in break mode**

**Your app has entered a break state, but no code is currently executing that is supported by the selected debug engine (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).**

And in the `Output` window I see

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.**

In [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/117927/the-application-is-in-break-mode-3.html) post it is recommended to set all check boxes for Common Language Runtime Excpetions in`Excpetion Settings` tab.
I have tried to check them in order to be able to get more information about what causes the exception

Here the screenshot of the error
[image]

I've tried to attach the project to different versions of Revit(I have installed on my PC Revit 2018, 2019 , 2020)
and none of them was successful

Here is also Output window log
[image]
Is there any way to explore what causes the error?

Comment: Why downvoted? Explain please.
I can add any additional info which will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to attach your addin to the Revit process.

You can tell Visual Studio to start the Revit program when you start to debug your addin:

From the project properties just browse to the Revit.exe path and it will start Revit, run the addin and this will allow you to debug.

[image]

The Revit.exe path doesn't have to be as the one from the example, it will be the one from your computer.

Comment: I have tried in this way, now I get another error, but more understandable.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and figured out that it was a conflict with a recently installed third-party add-in.  Uninstalling the add-in solved the problem.

Starting Revit and attaching to it is more efficient in my case then restarting Revit and reopening a project every time I want to test a change.